# Functions containing Array of Structures in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I made this structure to store entries but when I compute the total I'm getting a garbage value.I went through it a lot of times but still could not find the mistake.I also tried initializing the total but couldn't get he required answer .Every time I compute the total it gives the same garbage value as earlier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    char name[50];
    int Assignment[5];
    int Test[2];
    int Endsem;
    int Total;



}student;
void read(student s[],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the student");
        scanf("%s",&(s[i].name));
        printf("Enter the assignment marks \n ");
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&(s[i].Assignment[j]));
        }
        printf("\n Enter the Test marks \n ");
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&(s[i].Test[j]));
        }
        printf("\n Enter the EndSem marks \n");
        scanf("%d",&(s[i].Endsem));
        printf("\n \n ");
    }
}
void compute(student s[],int n)
{
    int i,j,d=0,m=0;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        s[i].Total=0;
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
          d+=(s[i].Assignment[j]);
        }
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
           m+=(s[i].Test);
        }
        s[i].Total=(d+m+(s[i].Endsem));
        printf("\n The total is %d out of 100",(s[i].Total));
    }
}
void display(student s[],int n)
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("The entries are");
        printf("%s",(s[i].name));
        printf("assignment marks \n ");
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf(" \n %d",(s[i].Assignment[j]));
        }
        printf("\nTest marks \n ");
        for(j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("%d \n ",(s[i].Test[j]));
        }
        printf("\n EndSem marks \n");
        printf("%d \n",(s[i].Endsem));
    }
}
void main()
{
    student s[1];

    read(s,1);
    display(s,1);
    compute(s,1);
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Because you display *before* you compute? That means you will print the value of an *uninitialized* variable, whose value will be *indeterminate* and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you.

Comment: side note: `scanf("%s",&(s[i].name));` --> `scanf("%49s",s[i].name);`

Comment: ...and even then, the first whitespace ends the scan, so `Weather Vane` would be truncated to `Weather`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
  m+=(s[i].Test);
```

`Test` is an array, not a normal (*scalar*) variable. It points to (or decays to) the starting address of the first element of the array. Adding that to an `int` makes no sense *here*.

You might want to write

```
 m+=(s[i].Test[j]);
```

That said, as I already commented, you should rewrite the `scanf()` statements for

- including the maximum field width to prevent buffer overfloe, like `scanf("%49s",...)` for an argument of array size 50
- pass the array name, instead of the address of array, as `%s` expects a pointer-to-char array, like `scanf("%49s",s[i].name);`